# How to a divide into a float instead of an integer? (python)

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, floating-point, int

So I have a tkinter program and it has 4 variable labels. To get one of the labels i need to divide a different variable by 100, but when I run the program, it is equal to 0. This is the part of the code: `eggzps = chookz / 100`, And here is the whole code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def moar_eggz():
    global eggzps, chookz

    chookz += 1


def update_labels():
    try:
        label1.config(text="Eggs: " + str(eggz))
        label2.config(text="Eggs Per Second: " + str(eggzps))
        label3.config(text="Egg Value: " + str(eggvalue))
        label4.config(text=" Chickens: " + str(chookz))
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e) # display exception to see problem

    # repeat it after 20ms 
    root.after(20, update_labels)

def main_loop():
    global eggz, eggzps
    eggzps = chookz / 100
    try:
        eggz += eggzps
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # display exception to see problem

    # repeat it after 1000ms 
    root.after(1000, main_loop)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Chicken Clicker")

eggz = 0
eggvalue = 0.2
chookz = 0
eggzps = 0


printeggzps = 0

# empty labels - `update_labels` will add text  
label4 = tk.Label(root)
label3 = tk.Label(root)
label2 = tk.Label(root)
label1 = tk.Label(root)
label4.pack()
label3.pack()
label2.pack()
label1.pack()

imagecnv = Image.open("img\\1.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagecnv)

openbutton = tk.Button(root, image=photo, width=500, height=500, command=moar_eggz)
openbutton.pack()

# run it first time at once
main_loop()
update_labels()


root.mainloop()
```

I have tried many things, most of them causing errors that I have had to post on here, but when the error is fixed, The problem is not solved. I have spent a whole day trying to get this to work, so I have resorted to just asking.

Any suggestions or answers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that still exhibits the problem! Also: is it really relevant that you are using the GUI lib tkinter?

Comment: Did you print `chookz` before the division to confirm, it is not `0` at this point?

Comment: `print()` variables to see what value you have - maybe you do `0/100` and then you have to get `0`

Comment: In Python 3, `0/100` returns `0.0` (a float), not `0` (an int).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int\int -> int result

int\float -> float result

use `100.0` instead of just 100

```
eggzps = chookz / 100.0
```

Comment: This is incorrect with python 3 ---> `import tkinter` is python 3